# SQL average of string values

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my table I have a column which has value M or F (male or female), and in my GROUP process, I want the average from M and F (for example M=0, F=1, then the average) for each made group.

I can't change the data to 0 and 1, because it comes from a much larger database, in which I cannot make adjustments. Can someone help?

Now I have something like:

```
SELECT Avg(variable1) AS Variable1, ...., Avg(variableX) AS VariableX
FROM Table1
GROUP BY variable3, varaible5, variable7;
```

I was told it might work using the COUNT statement, but I can't figure it out... Count just counts the number of something, but a want to count two things, and then divide then, I guess

I work in Microsoft Access

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select variable3, varaible5, variable7,
       avg(iif(gender = 'M', 0.0, 1.0)) as Ratio_F
from table1
group by variable3, varaible5, variable7
```

Comment: This is a valid answer for an Access query.  However, I would like to note that this considers everything that does not have a value of 'M' as 'F'.  Unexpected or incomplete values may skew the result.